# Horizontal scrolling crashes

Tags: javascript, horizontal-scrolling, mousewheel

This **JavaScript**-code provides simple and almost-cross-browser horizontal scrolling over the page by regular mouse wheel rolling:

```
var wheel = ("onwheel" in document)? "wheel" : ("onmousewheel" in document)? "onmousewheel" : undefined;
document.addEventListener(wheel, onWheel);

function onWheel(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var ammount = Math.round(e.deltaY) || Math.round(e.detail);
    window.scrollBy(ammount, 0);
}
```

You can [see for yourself on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/parzh/h7xyy6vd/), that it works not properly (crashes after three scrolls).
Why is it so? How to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a really interesting problem! It actually works on FF but as you say, it stops working on Chrome. I investigated it a bit and found this:

1) It doesn't crash, the listener is just not there any more

2) It doesn't require three scrolls, all you need to do is to scroll outside of the viewport (or visible frame) of the window to make the listener stop working. It's like addEventListener only applies to the visible area of the frame.

Sorry that I don't have an answer to your problem but maybe my findings can help you. (Maybe it's simply a bug in Chrome?)